# How to create Eclipse like Welcome page

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to create my own Welcome page like eclipse.I have search for but it shows for RCP Application but i want to create it inside Eclipse IDE So that when i click on menu, it should open Intro(help) page.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse.ui.intro extension point

All you need to do is to extend org.eclipse.ui.intro.configExtension and provide your implementation.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.intro.configExtension">
   <configExtension configId="org.eclipse.ui.intro.universalConfig" 
      content="intro/eclipse-tips.xml" />
</extension>
```

You have the whole tutorial here 
http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/short-tutorial-introwelcome

Comment: Thanks,But this example is adding content in Existing Welcome page.I want to create & open my own Welcome page.Can you please tell me that what is the way to do it?